# UiTableViewCell single selected checkmark for each section in the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, checkmark

How to make checkmark single selection to Each Section , with custom cells , when I realize this code , cell doesn't marked

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let it = PayMentSection(rawValue: indexPath.section) else {return}
        switch it {
        case .delivering:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid) as! MakePaymentTableViewCell
            cell.checkBox.isChecked = true
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        case .ordering:
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid2) as! MakePaymentTableViewCell2
            cell2.checkBox.isChecked = true

        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let it = PayMentSection(rawValue: indexPath.section) else {return}
        switch it {
        case .delivering:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid) as! MakePaymentTableViewCell
          cell.checkBox.isChecked = false
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        case .ordering:
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid2) as! MakePaymentTableViewCell2
          cell2.checkBox.isChecked = false

            cell2.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of the `cellForRowAt` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, implement `UITableViewDelegate's` **`tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)`** method like so,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let selectedIndexPathsInSection = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.filter({ $0.section == indexPath.section }), !selectedIndexPathsInSection.isEmpty {
        selectedIndexPathsInSection.forEach({ tableView.deselectRow(at: $0, animated: false) })
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Next, in both `MakePaymentTableViewCell` and `MakePaymentTableViewCell2` cells, override **`setSelected(_:animated:)`** method, i.e.

```
class MakePaymentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    //rest of the code...
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
        self.checkBox.isChecked = selected
    }
}
```

There is no need to implement `didSelectRowAt` and  `didDeselectRowAt` methods.

[image]

Comment: On this code I can make only one selection at 2 sections , I wan't to make single selection at each section

Comment: No , I don't know why , maybe it's depend on my version of Xcode

Comment: Which version are you using and what error are you getting after using this code?